# Loading audio using pygame.mixer

Tags: python, audio, pygame, mp3, mixer

I used a previous stack overflow post to help me develop the following code:

```
import os
import pygame
from pygame import *
import sys

GAME_FOLDER = os.path.dirname(__file__)
IMG_FOLDER = os.path.join(GAME_FOLDER, "img")


from time import sleep
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join(IMG_FOLDER, 'Noota.mp3'))
print("p")
pygame.mixer.music.play()
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    sleep(1)
print ("done")
```

And although the code loads without displaying an error message, it does not play the music; instead all I hear is a 'ticking' noise (about one tick per second). I was wondering if anyone knew why this is happening, and how I can fix it.

For reference, I am using python 3 on a mackintosh computer and the music file does play on the computer when loaded using a media player.

Thank you!

Comment: Pygame doc: [music](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html): "Be aware that MP3 support is limited. On some systems an unsupported format can crash the program, e.g. Debian Linux. Consider using OGG instead."

Answer (score 0):

First, you could try loading the audio file as a `pygame.mixer.Sound` and use `SoundName.play()` to check if its not `mixer.load()` that is broken
If it still happens, then its probably an issue with the audio file, go use a universal and up to date format like .ogg so it works on all platforms

Also, `time.sleep()` may be messing up the sound, as sleep stops every function, and in this case possibly the sound.
Heres an example if you are trying the sound method:

```
import os
import pygame
from pygame import *
import sys

GAME_FOLDER = os.path.dirname(__file__)
IMG_FOLDER = os.path.join(GAME_FOLDER, "img")


from time import sleep
noota = pygame.mixer.sound(os.path.join(IMG_FOLDER, 'Noota.mp3'))
print("p")
noota.play()
# Maybe the music is being cut off here v
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    sleep(1)
print ("done")
```